# Save model as an object to database and assign it later

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have several forms at one page, each form is defined in its own ViewModel in one MasterModel for that page. The issue is that if I submit any form, related ViewModel is assigned and I can process the form, but i also lost information of the form that was submitted previously.

Now what Iam doing is get the data from database and assign previously ViewModel (form) manually or to use AJAX call from page to fill the missing data for other forms.. but my question is, is it possible to store whole model for example in some JSON/XML/? format and use it later ?

for example

```
database.saveModel(model.FirstForm.ToJson())
model.FirstForm.FromJson(database.getModel())
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to store json data to the database to be able to use it later. PLease, see: [Storing JSON in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/23/storing-json-in-sql-server/); [JSON data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx)

Comment: @MaciejLos - the question is tagged sql-server-2008, but the native JSON features you link to are new features in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Ooops... i missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which helped me is this :

```
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(memorystream, model);
byte[] bytes = memorystream.ToArray();
```

now I can save bytes to the `VARBINARY(MAX)` sql column.

And I can also convert it back to the model

```
var result = Database.SqlQuery<byte[]>(...).First();
MemoryStream memorystreamd = new MemoryStream(result);
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
model = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memorystreamd) as CustomerVM;
```

But for the future project I will use an AJAX with Partial Views. I found nice article here https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

### en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON

BSON documents (objects) consist of an ordered list of elements. Each element consists of a field name, a type, and a value. Field names are strings. Types include:

- string
- integer (32- or 64-bit)
- double (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point number)
- date (integer number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch)
- byte array (binary data)
- boolean (true and false)
- null
- BSON object
- BSON array
- Javascript Code
- MD5 Binary Data
- Regular Expression

BSON types are nominally a superset of JSON types (JSON does not have a date or a byte array type, for example[3]), with one exception of not having a universal "number" type as JSON does.

---

## BSON Support in ASP.NET Web API 2.1

1. What is BSON?
2. Enabling BSON on the Server
3. Example HTTP Session
4. Using BSON with HttpClient
5. Serializing Top-Level Primitive Types
6. Additional Resources

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21

---

## C# and .NET MongoDB Driver

### [Driver Features](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/#driver-features)

### MongoDB Driver

> ...

### BSON Library

> A standalone BSON library with a serialization infrastructure that you can use to build high-performance serializers. For documentation on the BSON library, see BSON Reference.

### Core Library

> ...